# Another way to loop this code in AHK

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I have a working AHK code, but i am curious if there is a better/shorter way to do this loop,

```
a := b := aFunction() ; get a starting value for a and b 
loop,
{
    a := aFunction() ; call a function to get current a value
    if (a == b)
    continue
    Else
    {
        c := a - b ; this is to find how many new entry 
        loop,
        {
            d := dFunction(c) 
            b += c
            if (a == b )
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try crossposting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't need `,` after `loop`.

Comment: what is it supposed to do? Sorting? Calculate?

Comment: it is to get value from memory address, a and b is 1st/starting address, each time there's a new entry value of b would change. c is to determine the address range of the new entry, and d is the function to read the value from a to b (c)

Comment: Please post the entire script, including the functions.